# how to display the input value in page1 on page2 input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, local-storage

How to display the input value in page1 on page2 input?
Javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function showInput() {
    var value =  document.getElementById("user_input").value;  
    document.getElementById('display').value = value;

}
</script>
```

Page 1 html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <label><b>Enter a Message</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
    </form>

    <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();"><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Page 2 html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <label>Your input: </label>
    <p><input id='display'> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Do I need to use local storage? how to use it? 
Put this in page1

```
localStorage.setItem(id, value);
```

and this in page 2?

```
localStorage.getItem(id);
```

how to display the value in the input?
Can someone show me some examples? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, `localStorage` will do the job, In Page 1 `localStorage.setItem('id', document.getElementById("user_input").value);` after that in page 2 `document.getElementById('display').value = localStorage.getItem('id');`

Comment: Do I still need to put the function showInput()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

page1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script language="JavaScript">
function showInput() {
    var value =  document.getElementById("user_input").value;   // get value of message
    localStorage.setItem('val',value); // set value of message in local storage
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="page2.html" method="post"> // add action and method attributes in form tag
        <label><b>Enter a Message</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
        <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();"><br />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
function showInput() {
    var value = localStorage.getItem('val'); // get value of message from localstorage
    document.getElementById('display').value = value; // set it value to display input
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="showInput();">
    <label>Your input: </label>
    <p><input id='display'> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's working! Thank you so much. :)  but  it will only display the value after I refresh the page. How can I make it display straight after I click the button?

Comment: but there are 2 pages...page1.html and page2.html in that case without refresh how can we do it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Page1

```
<script>
   var value =  document.getElementById("user_input").value;
   localStorage.setItem("id",value);
</script>
```

Page2

```
<script>
    var value =localStorage.getItem("id");
    document.getElementById('display').value = value;
</script>
```